# Error: Illegal characters in path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ienumerable, enumerate, illegal-characters

I am using enumeratefiles to list all the files in a directory. Its throws an exception when it encounters a filename containing illegal characters and then stops the foreach loop that is listing the files. How can I make the foreach loop continue listing out filenames despite the exception? Any ideas?

Code:

```
try {

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(targetPath);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> allfiles = directory.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo file in allfiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}

}
catch (ArgumentException o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", o.Message);
}
```

Comment: you are saying that you have a file with invalid chars stored on your HDD?? anyway.. show something to start working with it (add a try..catch, add a check, who knows!) show us some code ;)

Comment: Its my downloadfolder and its full of sample projects for different coding languages so it probably from one of those countless folders. I still gotta find a way around this though. @BrianRasmussen Ive updated the code.

Comment: Are you sure the error is invalid chars on path? on what path?? or maybe you have a wrong file (not a path)..

Comment: Yes, the error shown in the post subject was directly copied from the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the try catch around the `foreach` loop. This means that if any one of the calls inside the loop fails your code will abort the rest of the loop.

Change the code to be something like this:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in allfiles)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", o.Message);
    }
}
```

You still should have the try ... catch around the `EnumerateFiles` in case that throws an error.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to move the `try / catch` to around the `Console.WriteLine`...?  Do you think that the `Console.WriteLine` is throwing the exception?  Seems likely that the `IEnumerable.Current` or `IEnumerable.MoveNext` is what's throwing here...

Comment: @ChrisF And yes, for some reason it was the Console.WriteLine that was throwing the exception.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - the description of the problem was that some of the filenames get output and then when it encounters an error in one it stops processing the whole list.

Comment: @ChrisF: So it was `file.Name` that was throwing, I see.  Not sure how I missed that on the first reading.